# Regular expressions from a list previously specified

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying the following: from each article print the month only which is located in either the 4th or the 5th line. The way I am attempting to do so is by:

```
m = 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May' 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Novemeber', 'December'

for i in range(len(sections)):

        date = re.search(r"[m]",sections[i][1:5])

        print(date)
```

First problem. I do not know how to search for a regular expression in my list "m". Second problem, I want to focus my search only in lines 0-5 of each article.

Comment: `r"[m]"` is just going to search for one of the characters in the set, aka, `m`. To search for any of a set of strings you want `String1|String2|etc`... https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @minitoto It's a tuple, it should work fine.

Comment: Also what lines are you searching?? You say "4th or 5th", your array index is `[1:5]`, and then you say "lines 0-5"...

Comment: I want it to search in the first 5 lines. I know where the problem is as well. So any ideas how to fix it? How should I write the search expression to find any of the months that appear in m?, Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> txt='''\
... Line 1
... Line 2
... Line 3
... Line 4
... Line 5 April'''
```

You can get the `i` through `j` line with `.splitlines()[i:j]`:

```
>>> txt.splitlines()[0:3]
['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3']
```

Now just construct a pattern that finds the months. Be sure to use `\b` to find whole word matches:

```
>>> months=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May' 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Novemeber', 'December']
>>> pat=re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(m) for m in months]), re.M)
```

Then search with your pattern in the slice of target lines:

```
>>> pat.search("\n".join(txt.splitlines()[0:5]))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107a2a9f0>
```

If you want to capture the line it appears on, you might do something like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/yT9pL5/1)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what sections is, i assume it's a multiline string:

```
import re

sections = 'some sections here'
dates = re.findall('\\b'+'\\b|\\b'.join(m), ' '.join(sections.splitlines()[0:4]))
```

Comment: Without `\b` this will match "Marching" and "Maya" and "Mayacaceae" and "Marchmont" and "Julyflower" and "Juneberry" etc. You need `\b` on either end but particularly on the end.